# Local DNS rewrite from host to host for web requests

Tags: dns, http, hosts

Is there some de-facto way for rewriting certain hostnames to other ones? Something like `/etc/hosts` for host to host instead of ip to host. Is this possible or should I create a local dns cname for that host?

**Update regarding the comments**

I want to use the local name that resolves to remote domain. The browser is just an example. I'm actually writing an ios app that requests resources from the internet, but I'd like to use local name for simulator-only runs. So to put it in another way I want my app to request http://localalias/, but that system would actually fetch http://remotehost.com/.

Comment: Do you control the host software and DNS zone for `remotehost.com`? In other words could you configure the web server at that location to respond to requests coming in under a different name?

Comment: No. I have no control over the remote host whatsoever.

Comment: Then see my answer below. Even if you were to configure your local network with a DNS hack to connect devices to the remote site using a local name, a properly configured remote site will NOT respond because of a site name mis-match. You will need to implement a proxy solution instead.

Comment: @Caleb: whether the remote host responds to a different name depends on the remote host configuration - you cannot know without trying. It's entirely possible that it does, although you're right that it's becoming less and less common these days.

Comment: What you need is to put an HTTP proxy between your application and the Internet. I don't have a recommendation offhand; Squid can surely do this and is available for OSX but it's probably overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS CNAMEs would be the de-facto way to do this.

**Edit:** In light of comments below...

I don't think you'll be able to do what you are trying to do. You're trying to trick the browser or some other program into thinking something is an address it's not. The problem is that something is also going pass the name of the resource it wants so that the remote server knows what site to dish up. More than one site could be hosted on a given ip address. The browser sends the site it wants as part of it's request, just re-routing the traffic via a DNS hack is not going to be enough because the browser would be asking for a resource name that the remote site doesn't know anything about.

You will need to setup a full proxy system on your local system. It needs to either respond with standard browser headers to redirect you to the remote resource, or it needs to fetch the remote resource itself then pass through the data. This could be done with apache, squid, or any number of other proxy and http hosting solutions. If you give more details of your scenario we could be more specific.

Comment: how and where should I go about this?

Comment: Are you trying to create aliases for domains you control or other domains around the net? Do you have bind running anywhere already?

Comment: I have a domain (say www.ontheinternet.com). I want to access it on my browser via http://ontheinternetbutlocal/. I'm using OSX. I think it has some sort of mDNSResponder.

Comment: Ok that's a different question than I thought you were asking. See my edited answer.

Comment: Please see my updated question. I don't think I can be more specific .)

Answer (score 0):

Each line of [/etc/hosts](http://linux.die.net/man/5/hosts) has the format:

```
ip fqdn aliases
```

where:

- *ip* is the IP address of a host;
- *fqdn* is the DNS fully-qualified name (the one that you would put
  in DNS `A` and `PTR` records)
- *aliases* is a (possibly empty) list of alternate names for the same
  host (these would be `CNAME` records in DNS)

So, you can add any alternative/local name in the *aliases* part.  For
example, if you have installed a webapp on `http://127.0.0.1:80` but
want to test it using the production site name `http://webapp.example.org`,
you could write this into `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost webapp.example.org
```

Comment: Unfortunately I think this guy is trying to do the exact oposite of this -- tricking clients into using a name that looks like a local site to access a remote resource that he doesn't control.

Comment: @Caleb: The comment above says "I want to access `www.ontheinternet.com` on *my* browser via `ontheinternetlocal`".  I read this as wanting a local-only alias... Let's wait for the OP to clarify the question.

Comment: We do need clarification, but even the way you read it, you could create an alias with the ip and local name in `/etc/hosts`, but it would still fail. In your example the local webserver could be configured to respond to requests for `webapp.example.org`. Doing this backwards, the site `www.ontheinternet.com` isn't going to answer requests for `ontheinternetlocal`.